# controlTextDidChange with 2 nstextfields - call different selectors

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

cocoa newbie here

i have 2 nstextfields connected with controlTextDidChange.
it works fine.

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)anotif{
    [self eval];
}
```

when either of the textfields change eval is called.

what i want to do is check the textfield that changed and if it's the first one call eval1,
if it's the second call eval2.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the `NSTextField`s are `field1` and `field2`, all you have to do is check which one of them is the sender object, given along with the notification.

**E.g.:**

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)anotif
{
    if ([anotif object]==field1)
    {
        // field1 processing
    }
    else
    {
        // field2 processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I found it.

I set tags on both `NSTextField`s.

Then, I can get the tag number with :

```
[[anotif object] tag]
```

Comment: Or you could just see if `[anotif object] == myField1`