# How to discover each UI object sent the message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am still learning Objective C/Cocoa and I am building a program with a simples interface. In this interface, there are some NSTextField which has this delegate:

```
- (void) controlTextDidChange: (NSNotification *) obj{
    //Some code here
}
```

When the user changes the the text of any of these NSTextField the program needs to check if the number inside the NSTextField is an integer. If the provided string is not an Integer I want to display a dialog with the error and each NSTexField the error occurred, since I have more than one NSTextField connected to this method.

My question is: how can I discover each UI object sent the message to the  controlTextDidChange method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)anotif
{
    if ([anotif object]==field1)
    {
        // field1 processing
    }
    else
    {
        // field2 processing
    }
}
```

From
[controlTextDidChange with 2 nstextfields - call different selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011838/controltextdidchange-with-2-nstextfields-call-different-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the UITextField subviews as properties, you can set tag for every UITextField subview change the code @Bruno provided as follows:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)anotif
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[anotif object];
    if (textField.tag == 1)
    {
        // field1 processing
    }
    else
    {
        // field2 processing
    }
}
```